# Building a .xap file from command line

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Is it possible to build a .xap file from the command line like you would build a .cs file from csc.exe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) to build a project or a solution. From the Visual Studio Command Prompt, change your working directory to where your Solution / Project is:

> >MSBuild YourSolution.sln

And now it is built. You *do* need the Windows Phone 7 Development tools installed on the machine for this to work.

Comment: Do we need visual studio to be installed to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just invoke devenv from the visual studio command prompt that is installed as part of the SDK. MSDN has the relevant documentation.